# variable value does not change after for loop c#

Tags: c#, ffmpeg

I need to use the formula `height` to get a new int value for each cycle, but it is always equal to `180`, provided that the index variable changes.

```cs
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ///some code
        WorkContainer.StartUp(Source, Mode, Output);
    }
}

internal class WorkContainer
{
    public static void StartUp(string Source, string Mode, string Output)
    {   
        ///some code
        int maxWidth = 180;
        int maxHeight = 420;
        int framerate = 30;

        switch (Mode)
        {
            case "Bouncing":
                int delta = 5;
                double bouncesPerSecond = 1.5;
                int index = 0;
                int height = (int)(index == 0 ? maxHeight : (Math.Floor(Math.Abs(Math.Cos(index / (framerate / bouncesPerSecond) * Math.PI) * (maxHeight - delta))) + delta));
                ffmpegWork.ffmpegPngChangeResolution(CurrentDirectory, RandomTempFolderIdentity, index, maxWidth, height);
                break;
        }
    }
}

internal class ffmpegWork 
{
    public static void ffmpegPngChangeResolution(string CurrentDirectory, string RandomTempFolderIdentity, int index, int maxWidth, int height)
    {
        int ImgValues = new DirectoryInfo($"{CurrentDirectory}/Temp{RandomTempFolderIdentity}/img/").GetFiles().Length;
        for (int i = 0; i < ImgValues; i++, index++)
        {
            try
            { 
                Process compiler = new Process();
                        compiler.StartInfo.FileName = $"{CurrentDirectory}/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg";
                        compiler.StartInfo.Arguments = $"-y -i {CurrentDirectory}/Temp{RandomTempFolderIdentity}/img/img-{i + 1}.png -vf scale={maxWidth}:{height} -c:a libvorbis {CurrentDirectory}/Temp{RandomTempFolderIdentity}/webmImg/img-{i + 1}.png";
                        compiler.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                        compiler.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                        compiler.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                        compiler.Start();
                Console.WriteLine($"png frame - {i + 1}/{ImgValues}\nheight={height}");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

console output>>>

```
png frame - 1/n
height=180
png frame - 2/n
height=180
png frame - 3/n
height=180
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here

```
int height = (int)(index == 0 ? maxHeight : (Math.Floor(Math.Abs(Math.Cos(index / (framerate / bouncesPerSecond) * Math.PI) * (maxHeight - delta))) + delta));
```

index is always 0, so height always == maxHaight

Comment: this is not true [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/7vg5gvn)

Comment: @Dokoa You literally set it on the previous line: `int index = 0;` The code you posted cannot ever have a different value for index. Your screenshot clearly shows either a different variable named `index` or you've manually set the value.

Comment: how do i fix it, if i remove index=0 from it then i will get error with empty variable value?

Comment: si,ply comment out the line 'int index = 0;'

Comment: Error CS0103 The name "index" does not exist in the current context.

Comment: @Dokoa you need to do something in between `int index = 0;` and `int height = (int)(index == 0 ? maxHeight : (Math.Floor(Math.Abs(Math.Cos(index / (framerate / bouncesPerSecond) * Math.PI) * (maxHeight - delta))) + delta));`

Otherwise, as has already been said, you will always have `index == 0`.

Comment: @Dokoa - the screen shot you posted sugegsted that at one time you had another variable called 'index' - you clearly have deleted it